# Need advice on how to setup this rather odd site (in Django)

Tags: php, html, django, ftp, dreamweaver

I could really do with some advice here. I'm new to Django, but understand the fundamentals. Though I need some advice on how to setup this site (that's not too conventional really).

I have a client who has a site that is mainly static HTML pages (alot of them) which he prefers as he does the content in Dreamweaver. Trust me, I've tried to show him the way of a CMS, but he really does prefer to do it this way... He has multi-lingual pages that he has stored in different folders, which he uploads himself using FTP. The basic setup, at the moment, is like this:

/index.php
/en/lesson1.php
/en/lesson2.php
/fr/lesson1.php
/fr/lesson2.php
/da/lesson1.php
/da/lesson2.php
etc...

Now, the PHP is small little bits and bobs inside these pages. But it really is mostly HTML in them. He opens the whole page in Dreamweaver for him to layout and add his content where appropriate. He's now asked for more functionality, like people logging in and having a members area, setting up a better mailing list etc... I'm thinking this should now be done in Django, as I don't fancy making something so complex in PHP with an admin area etc. I want to avoid stuff like Cake and Symphony.

Is there anyway that I can build the admin area in Django that will allow him to manage his banners, his members, his mailing list etc. But Django can be setup where so whatever URL the visitors goes to: like www.site.com/en/lesson1/ and Django will just load up the HTML for the visiter, which is basically in the /en/lesson.html place on the FTP that my client has uploaded?

I'm trying to strike a balance where he can still do his usual Dreamweaver and FTP thing, but have the power of Django for all the other things I want to incorporate.

Any ideas, solutions, tips or tricks for this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [Generic Views](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter11/) to display static content.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply set access him for template directory. And show him:

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/topics/templates/#topics-templates
http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/ref/templates/builtins/#ref-templates-builtins

About area in admin, you have to develop it and provide him proper mechanism to manage the data.

I hope I understand questions correclty.